# How to use .then method for vcRecaptchaService.execute()?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, recaptcha, invisible-recaptcha

I am using [anuglar-recaptcha](https://github.com/VividCortex/angular-recaptcha) for adding Google Invisible Recaptcha to my login form

The issue I am facing is, immediately after I call vcRecaptchaService.execute, if I print the `recaptcha_reponse` I will see `undefined` as output. But if I print `recaptcha_reponse` few seconds afterwards by using a test function `printRecaptchaReponse` I will see the `recaptcha_reponse` getting printed.

The Issue here is, the library function `vcRecaptchaService.execute()` is not returning a `$promise` here. Its actually returning `none`

Is there any way to promisify this ?

**Whats the ISSUE:**

```
// 1. Call this function from html first
$scope.testRecaptchaExecute = function() {
    vcRecaptchaService.execute($scope.widgetId);
    console.log($scope.user.recaptcha_reponse);
    // undefined :-(
    return();
}

// 2. Call this function from html few seconds after testRecaptchaExecute() is called

$scope.printRecaptchaReponse = function() {
    console.log($scope.user.recaptcha_reponse);
    //JVRk4cZ4J_RluoH2
}
```

**WHAT I want:**
Something like,

`vcRecaptchaService.execute().then(ret => { //do something here })`
Issue with this code is vcRecaptchaService.execute don’t return a promise. This code won’t work

**Question Summary**
How to use `.then` method for `vcRecaptchaService.execute()`?

Comment: `How to use .then` ... check the code in `WHAT I want` - that's how ... oh, except  `vcRecaptchaService.execute()` doesn't return a Promise ...

Comment: You got it @JaromandaX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this working code for `recaptcha`

Javascript

```
$scope.captcha = {
    response: null,
    widgetId: null,
    modelKey: 'test key',
    size: 'normal',
    setResponse: function (response) {
        $scope.captcha.response = response;
    },
    setWidgetId: function (widgetId) {
        $scope.captcha.widgetId = widgetId;
    },
    cbExpiration: function () {
        vcRecaptchaService.reload($scope.captcha.widgetId);
        $scope.captcha.response = null;
    }
}
```

Html

```
<div ng-model="form.recaptcha" 
     size="captcha.size" 
     vc-recaptcha theme="'light'" 
     key="captcha.modelKey" 
     on-create="captcha.setWidgetId(widgetId)"
     on-success="captcha.setResponse(response)" 
     on-expire="captcha.cbExpiration()" 
     required>
</div>

<p ng-show="!form.recaptcha" class="error">Please resolve the captcha</p>
```

Comment: Worked perfectly for me. Thanks a lot Gaurav